# Bootstrap tooltip not appearing in div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div tag that aligned to right. So I put bootstrap tooltip to left of it. but not appearing.

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                <div class="map-nav-container">
                    <div class="mnc-button-group">
                        <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hello">+</button>                            
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is css code

```
.map-nav-container{
    position:absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    z-index: 1000;
}
.mnc-button-group{ 
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

And [here is working](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/28bjaae3/3/) code.

Comment: fiddle seems to work fine for me in chrome, your problem may be that `#map` isn't positioned though

Comment: Same here in chrome and firefox

Comment: I updated button alignment now to right.

Comment: Look @ my answer. I've updated the Fiddle again.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case Webice has answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He want that tooltip on the left side of the button.

```
.map-nav-container{
    position:absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    overflow: visible; 
    z-index: 1000;
}
.mnc-button-group{ 
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28bjaae3/4/

```
overflow: visible;
```